# WebClient неверно скачивает файл

Tags: c#, assembly

Есть хостинг на котором лежит файл. Файл создан из dll библиотеки прочитанной  `ReadAllBytes` и сохраненной `WriteAllBytes` как массив байтов, на это не важно. Сама по себе библиотека работает. Если брать новый файл - массив байт и загружать его как dll тоже все хорошо :

```
byte[] all = File.ReadAllBytes(@"ByteDll.mvvm");
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(all);
object o = a.CreateInstance("Library.Class1");
Type t = a.GetType("Library.Class1");
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("mess");
mi.Invoke(o, null);
```

проблема начинается если я выкладываю ByteDll на хостинг и потом скачиваю его так:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://iwwwi.esy.es/", "ByteDll.mvvm");
```

Скачанный файл на четверть меньше по размеру и при запуске возникает ошибка :

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "3547 bytes loaded from ReadWriteBytes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Хотя если я просто руками скачаю тот же файл он будет работать как положено.

Пробовал так :

```
byte[] all = client.DownloadData("http://iwwwi.esy.es/");
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(all);
```

результат тот же.

Comment: Очевидно, скачивается что-то не то, раз файл по размеру меньше. Вы бы приложили ссылку на сам хостинг, а так же адрес, по которому пытаетесь скачать файл.

Comment: Вы имеете на руках два файла. Сравните их содержимое.

Comment: У вас всегда одинаковый размер? Проверьте `Content-Length` из заголовков HTTP. Может у вас происходит обрыв соидинения?  При обрыве нужно перескачать. Проверьте за сколько шагов у вас идёт скачивание, может у вас не разрешены редиректы, или нет доступа. Посмотрите в текстовом редакторе что записано в all (для этого, например, сохрание в файл)

Comment: @Geslot добавил ссылку на хостинг

Comment: @nick_n_a перескачивал не раз. если руками скачиваю то все норм, если программно то не работает

Comment: Ещё раз, 1. сохраните байты в файл - и посмотрите что там. (у меня приходит "бан")  2. Убедитесь что размер байт совпадает с `ContentLength`.

Comment: @nick_n_a какой бан ?

Comment: @nick_n_a `Убедитесь что размер байт совпадает с ContentLength` если скачанный файл меньше то очевидно же что  несовпадает.

Comment: Запустите Fiddler, и посмотрите в чём разница.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis это инструмент для JS совершенно мне не знакомый.

Comment: @Сергей JS? Не знаком, освойте http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Нет, не очевидно. Если совпадает ContentLength - у вас проблема на сервере. Если не совпадает - на клиенте.

Comment: @nick_n_a `может у вас не разрешены редиректы, или нет доступа.` к сожалению, я совершенно вас не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто адрес был не правильны. Вот как нужно было :

```
        var all = client.DownloadData("http://iwwwi.esy.es/ByteDll.mvvm");
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(all);
```